# How to convert a byte into a String that displays its hex value (0x0e -> "0E")

Tags: java, string, hex, byte

So i have a piece of code, which converted byte[] from a binary file into int[] which then went on to be converted to String.

Example: 02 09 1A would translate to "2926" using `String.valueOf(byte);`

But this is where the fun begins: the old Code already split up the array before it became String so it didn't matter. Now i have code which needs to somehow figure out if there is a 2 9 or 29... How can i get the String to
 
 - stay in Hex instead of "switching" to decimal and 
 - keep the zeros in the string
so i can always grab the next two chars, figure out which info they display and go on?

Input:
 05 06 1D 11 07 08 01 32 21 28 2F 20 2E 21 34 22 25 33 01 02 09 0A FF 0B 0C 
  2!(/ .!4"%3 
ÿ

 Current Output: 562917781503340473246335234375112910-11112

Expected Output: 05061D110708013221282F202E21342225330102090AFF0B0C

*(Didn't put my old code in here since it's based on int which is crap)*

Comment: Can you show some inputs and outputs? Right now your question is not very clear.

Comment: Added Input, expected and real output. Also to clarify: java makes FF -1 so the old code stopped reading here, but its inevidable to use FF at this point of the binary.

Comment: Is the input in a `byte[]`? Also, why is "2!(/ .!4"%3 ÿ" at the end of the input?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this code works exactly the way i wanted ^^ The reason this random stuff is at the end of input is, that i put the ASCII characters representing the hex value under the hex value so noone could think "05 " would be the bytes 0x30 0x35 0x20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `byte[]` as input, and you want to output a string that is all those bytes, in hex form, joined together:

```
private static String byteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : byteArray) {
        int i = Byte.toUnsignedInt(b);
        if (i < 16) {
            builder.append("0");
        }
        builder.append(Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase());
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Note the use of [`Byte.toUnsignedInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-). This converts things like `-1` *the byte* to the `int` `0xff`. This is required because Java's bytes are signed.

Also note where I pad with `0`. I only do this if the byte is a single digit in hex. `i < 16` is the condition to check this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
  char[] hexVals = {'0', '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A', 'B','C','D','E','F'};
  byte[] bytes = {5, 6, (byte)0xAB, (byte)0xde};   // sample input
  char[] output = new char[bytes.length*2];
  // split each byte's hex digits into two chars
  for(int i=0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
     output[2*i] = hexVals[(bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xf];  // HO nibble
     output[2*i+1] = hexVals[bytes[i] & 0xf];       // LO nibble
  }
  System.out.println(new String(output)); //  0506ABDE
```

Comment: Also a pretty good solution, since i have to write the same code in Assembler, C, C++ and Java i will definitly make use of it in the other languages where i cant access the libraries. I will leave the accepted answer to Sweeper since this Post was decleared Java but thank you for showing me this (i cant access any libraries in c and assembler since the code is for reading header used in a java game and also for all kinds of files in my OS) :)